# Duplicate HTML - page space saver

Tags: jquery, html

I have two big blocks of HTML on one page, they are exactly the same but I need them in two places. Is there a method that allows me to delete one block and "call/load" the other block instead. Therefore reduce my page size/speed and update admin. I know there is a jquery snippet that calls/loads another html page and places the content in the id (below) but can this be done with content on the same page?

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#div").load('page.html');
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use

```
var new_div = $('#div').clone();
```

And then use append/prepend/insertBefore etc to insert it in the DOM.

Make sure you change the id of the clone or there might be complications with DOM manipulations after the clone is inserted.